# Using JavaScript or jQuery, how can I get the RGB color where ever the mouse is moving specially in <img> or <div> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image, `<img src="/meAndMy/face.jpg" />`. I am trying to get the RGB color when ever or where ever I move my mouse cursor.

How can I do this with jQuery or plain JavaScript? e.g: http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/158/index.html

**Follow up (for copy paste testing):**

```
<?=$this->headScript(); ?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{

   var image = new Image();
   var ctx = $('#panel')[0].getContext("2d");

   /* Load the picture empty.jpg */
   image.onload = function () 
   {
     ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
   }
   /* How can i reload later new?
      image.empty; */
   image.src = "/agents/empty.jpg";

   /* On mouse over to my image, show me the background with RGB  
      change mousemove to click if requires */
   $('#panel').mousemove(function(e) 
   { 
    /* Leave as it is */
    var canvasOffset = $(this).offset();
    var canvasX = Math.floor(e.pageX - canvasOffset.left);
    var canvasY = Math.floor(e.pageY - canvasOffset.top);
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(canvasX, canvasY, 1, 1);
    var pixel = imageData.data;    
    var pixelColor = "rgba("+pixel[0]+", "+pixel[1]+", "+pixel[2]+", "+pixel[3]+")";

    /* Meat */
    $(document.body).css('background-color',pixelColor);

   });

});

</script>

<body>
  <canvas id="panel" width="500" height="333"></canvas>
<body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it just like the script for that demo does. Note that the demo does not use an img element, rather it loads the image into a canvas element. The canvas API allows you to get the pixel data like so:

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(canvasX, canvasY, 1, 1);
var pixel = imageData.data;
```

See the [HTML 5 canvas API](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#2dcontext) for details.

If for whatever reason you are required to load the image into the img element, as opposed to a canvas element, you could:

1. Dynamically create a canvas element with the same size and at the same location as the img.
2. Copy the image data from img to canvas via the drawImage method from the canvas context.
3. Hide the img element, leaving the canvas in its place.

Comment: As edited, that appears to work. At least it works for me, using a local image.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the color of point of an image only with JavaScript ( without the Canvas support ). You need some server-side.

For example: you have a jpg image. You point somewhere, click. An event-listener should send to the server the coordinates and a server-side application will determine what the color is ( the image should be present on the server, of course). see http://muffinresearch.co.uk/code/javascript/pickr/

For your example - the image is read and displayed by a canvas element. An event-listener gets the coordinates of the click and with [getImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas#Getting_the_pixel_data_for_a_context) gets a copy of the pixel. The [data property](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-tutorial/) contains info  for a red, green, blue, and alpha component.

Comment: Thanks, nice info. But after few years many people will simply use HTML5 i think. Its better now already i get start familiar with it.

Comment: Of course, but nowadays there are still questions about support for IE7&8, which do not support HTML5.

Comment: We suspend IE forever. We are either telling our users to use Chrome/Opera else no contract.