# Text color relative to image behind it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors

I have a strong feeling that this isn't possible - but that's why I'm here.

I have a site which has a full screen slideshow on the homepage and a header with a transparent background and dark text/content. The problem is that on darker images you cannot see the content as it is dark too.

Obviously I could give the div a background but this isn't what the design calls for.

Is there any way I can color the text relative to the background, possibly an 'invert' color effect or something similar?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. store the information in the file name (easiest) - e.g image1_light.png, imagex_dark.jpg and look at the _light or _dark. OR
2. [How to pick good contrast RGB colors programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260989/how-to-pick-good-contrast-rgb-colors-programmatically)
3. canvas/html5 [Using JavaScript or jQuery, how can I get the RGB color where ever the mouse is moving specially in <img> or <div> elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985722/using-javascript-or-jquery-how-can-i-get-the-rgb-color-where-ever-the-mouse-is)

The demo to look at is http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/158/index.html where you need to determine the position of the text and see what the main color is under the text

`$(".navigation").position()` is {top: 30, left: 381}
`$(".navigation").width())` is 214
`$(".navigation").height())` is 68

I would think the code would be something like this

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/jwL5S/)

```
var ctx,canvas;   
$(function(){ // on page load, this should likely be on image transition

  // creating canvas object in memory. 
  // Since I do not append it anywhere it is not rendered
  canvas = $("<canvas/>")[0]; // a jQuery object on its own does not work
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var image = new Image(); // create an image object in memory
  image.onload = function () {
      // resize
      canvas.width=this.width;
      canvas.height=this.height; 
      // render the image on the canvas
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0); 
      var nav =  $(".navigation"); // get the navigation container
      // find a pixel about in the middle where the navigation would be
      var pos = {left: nav.position().left+(nav.width()/2), top: nav.position().top+(nav.height()/2) }
      var pixel = ctx.getImageData(pos.left,pos.top, 1, 1).data;
      $canvas=null; // no longer need this canvas 
      var invertedPixelColor = "rgba("+(255-pixel[0])+", "+(255-pixel[1])+", "+(255-pixel[2])+", "+1+")"; // invert it, ignoring the alpha channel
      nav.css("color",invertedPixelColor); // set the nav text to inverted color
      // here you could save the colour and reuse it 
      // if the user navigates to the same image
  }
  image.src = $(body).css('background-image'); // load the image, triggering the calc

});
```

Comment: If I put the canvas element on top of an img element, will I still be able to find the color like that?

Comment: like in the tutorial you have to render the image on the canvas.

Comment: I do not render the canvas. Assuming the image is the size of the window (otherwise we will need to do something else)

Comment: I think this is definitely the closest solution to what I'm looking for so I'll give you that little green tick we all strive for. Do you think it would be complicated to get an average color from a defined area, in case there is a randomly different colored pixel? I guess I'd just add the colors of several pixels and / by no. of pixels?

Comment: I am in the process of actually implementing this since I find it interesting. My progress is held up due to canvas issues I need to solve. My (so far non-working) test is [>here<](http://plungjan.name/test/detectbackground.html)

Comment: @mplungjan Wow - that's great! I'll keep an eye on it ;)

Comment: We could span each letter and give it a colour of its own ;) by the way, feel free to credit me in your code - if you need help implementing it at the site you posted I would like to help

Comment: @mplungjan it's a shame I actually never went through with this! I hope you made use of it!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by brute force. Determine yourself what color of text to put with each image and then setting the color with Javascript when ever the image changes based on the name of new image. Of course that means that if you changed any images you would have to change the Javascript too.

Comment: Ahem - I believe that was my suggestion #1 :) - and why need to change the javascript? Just store image1_dark.png image23_light.png

Comment: I was assuming a need for more than simply light or dark text, where each image might need a separate specific color text that would have to be coded individually. In that case adding another image would require adding to the code to handle it. Perhaps I was overcomplicating the issue.