# Getting the background color of x,y coordinate using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, background-color

I want to get the background color while marking a point on a image, by using jquery. I didn't know how to get the color of a image on certain x, y points. Any help is much appreciated,

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985722/using-javascript-or-jquery-how-can-i-get-the-rgb-color-where-ever-the-mouse-is

Answer (score 0):

You have to canvas element take the image and place it in the canvas the at the x,y co-ordinate you can simply get the color using

```
context.getImageData(x, y, width, height);
```