# How to invert color of underlying div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two different divs, one on top of the other.

```
<div id="upper" style="background-color:transparent;z-index:2
                       width:15px;height:15px;
                       position:absolute;
                       top:0px;left:0px;
                       filter:invert(100%)"></div>
<div id="lower" style="background-color:#ff9900;z-index:1
                       width:100%;height:100px;
                       position:absolute;
                       top:0px;left:0px"></div>
```

The lower div can change color during time, the upper dive must get the lower color but inverted!

It seems easy but consider this condition: the upper div does not know what it has below itself, it can be more divs for example. In the scenario I wrote, I just made it easy, but I cannot select a particular element and get its color.

How to do?

In the example you saw I used `filter:invert(100%)` as I thought it could be the solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: I thought it was `-webkit-filter: invert();`

Comment: The background color for `#upper` is transparent. When you apply `filter: invert` on `transparent` it will still be `transparent`. There is no way to make an element to "know" what under it. However, there are many other ways to do it, such as using a `<canvas>`.

Comment: you forgot a ';' after each z-index property

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question. I told you that below you can have every possible div not strictly a parent in the DOM!!!

Comment: So show us the full HTML them, CSS cannot affect elements higher in the DOM which, apparently, you are trying to do. If you can change the HTML structure...we can talk again.

Comment: Probably I explained it not correctly... also showing you the full html does not make sense. This is not a matter of DOM hierarchy but a matter of what comes upper of an object and lower to it! Just how graphical objects get stacked and this happens indipendently by the DOM hierarchy!

Comment: If you plan to use canvas, you can look at this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985722/using-javascript-or-jquery-how-can-i-get-the-rgb-color-where-ever-the-mouse-is

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div id="upper" style="background-color:#ff9900;z-index:2;
                       width:15px;height:15px;
                       position:absolute;
                       top:0px;left:0px;
                       -webkit-filter:invert(100%);
                       filter:invert(100%);"></div>
<div id="lower" style="background-color:#ff9900;z-index:1;
                       width:100%;height:100px;
                       position:absolute;
                       top:0px;left:0px"></div>
```

Basically, as stated in the comments by 'Derek', you must have a color to invert. And also, from "Apolo", -webkit-filter:invert(), should also be used for webkit based browsers.

You can combine standard methods with -webkit methods for better cross browser support.

Please test here to make sure your browser supports this feature >> [CSS3 Filter Tests](http://www.propra.nl/playground/css_filters/)

In my tests on jsFiddle, this doesn't appear to be supported in my version of FireFox (28.0)

Comment: standard property such as filter must be ***after*** vendor properties. =)

Comment: and I'm pretty sure he needs to add a ';' after z-index properties

Comment: you are correct.  also, seems that invert doesn't function properly in firefox -.-

Comment: I know this can be done using JavaScript, however the OP was requesting a CSS solution. He will just need to be aware that this is not supported in all browsers.

Comment: @Michael - "upper dive must get the lower color but inverted!" .. the inversion on an upper div that is transparent will use the lower color for the value to invert.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the issue

```html
<div id="upper" style="z-index:2;
                       width:150px;height:200px;
                       position:absolute;
                       top:0px;left:0px;
                       backdrop-filter:invert(100%);
                       "></div>
<div id="lower" style="background-color:#ff9900;z-index:1;
                       width:100%;height:100px;
                       position:absolute;
                       top:0px;left:0px"></div>
```

Comment: please explain your answer

Comment: in Firefox, this doesn't work unless I manually go into about:config and set both `gfx.webrender.all` and `layout.css.backdrop-filter.enabled` to "true".  This is fine for myself, but how do I get everybody who visits my web site to do this?