# Get first pixel's color of an image ( JS / jQuery )

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, colors, pixel

I have - for example - this pic:

```
var imgSrc = "http://scottkleinberg.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/icon-512x512.png";
```

And i need only variable with RGB or RGBA or HEX color on first position pixel (0,0):

```
var color = getFirstPixelColor( imgSrc ); // Should return #AAE8FE or 170,323,254 or 170,323,254,1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a resuln, but only with PHP:

```
$imgObject = imagecreatefrompng('http://scottkleinberg.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/icon-512x512.png');
$fillColor = imagecolorat($imgObject, 0, 0);

 $rgba = array(
    ($fillColor >> 16) & 0xFF,
    ($fillColor >> 8) & 0xFF,
     $fillColor & 0xFF,
);

print_r($rgba);
```

When is the image JPG or JPEG format:

```
$imgObject = imagecreatefromjpeg('http://scottkleinberg.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/icon-512x512.png');
$fillColor = imagecolorat($imgObject, 0, 0);

 $rgba = array(
    ($fillColor >> 16) & 0xFF,
    ($fillColor >> 8) & 0xFF,
     $fillColor & 0xFF,
);

print_r($rgba);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use HTML5 canvas. You can not get color value directly by image.

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(canvasX, canvasY, 1, 1);
var pixel = imageData.data;
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985722/using-javascript-or-jquery-how-can-i-get-the-rgb-color-where-ever-the-mouse-is) SO question will answer you clearly.

Comment: where ctx = ? Although, Your answer is correct, please, try to explain it a bit more. Also don't forget, the OP asked for getting first pixel by only knowing the src. Seems like there are some steps missing from this answer.