# Get color of specific pixel in image

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image (`<img>` element). I want to extract the color of specific pixel from this image. Obvious way is to create a canvas of the same dimensions as of the image, then using the function `getImageData()` to get the color. Is there other way to get the pixel color without create a whole image canvas?

Comment: No - I'm afraid there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

To do this with javascript, you need to use HTML5 canvas. You cannot get color value directly from the image.

See this SO for some in-depth: [Using JavaScript or jQuery, how can I get the RGB color where ever the mouse is moving specially in <img> or <div> elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985722/using-javascript-or-jquery-how-can-i-get-the-rgb-color-where-ever-the-mouse-is)

If you can do it server-side, I have done something similar with PHP before (getting average color) so I know that with PHP you could do this.